# What is the difference between niger and ater?

Tags: word-comparison, adjective, color

L&S gives descriptions of [*niger*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DN%3Aentry+group%3D13%3Aentry%3Dniger1) and [*ater*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D85%3Aentry%3Dater1), but the difference is is not clear to me at all.
Both mean black, but there appears to be a difference in nuance — as practically always when two different words mean (almost) the same thing.

I get the impression that *ater* is more in the direction of "mournful" and *niger* is more "malicious" or "glowless".
But I might be wrong and there might be more to it.
For example, I'm not sure if I could use *ater* for glowing black and *niger* for matte black if I need to make the distinction.

Could someone compare these two adjectives for me?

Comment: I remember reading that *ater* is shiny and *niger* matte, but I will need to find the source.

Comment: @Draconis A source for that distinction would be very interesting. I don't recall ever reading on the matter.

Comment: @Draconis. The link to L/S says exactly the opposite:  ater is "black; and specif., coalblack, lustreless-black, sable, dark (opp. albus, lustreless-white, and diff. from niger, glossy black,"

Comment: the issue of color is dealt on [*Be Not Afraid of the Dark* by Shelley P. Haley](https://ms.fortresspress.com/downloads/0800663403_Chapter%20one.pdf) pages 31-33.  Not sure I can see clear examples, but it reads: "*Albus and ater connote a matte-like quality, whereas candidus and niger imply luster and brightness*". This seems to be in line with L/S as @fdb writes above.

Comment: @d_e Would you like to write that up into an answer? Citation of that chapter and L&S would make a strong point.

Answer (score 8):

The adjective “ater” goes just  in the direction of “dark” in the sense of "mournful" / “gloomy”, since  the “dies atri” were considered unlucky days (See Macrobius, Saturnalia, book 1, chapter 16, section 21,  and  Livy, Ab Urbe Condita, book 22, chapter 10, section 6 ), while “niger” means “black” and sometimes  “malicious”/”bad”/” wicked “ (See Cicero, Pro A.Caecina, 27)  or “inauspicious” as  in “nigra avis” (bird of ill omen) and “funereal” as in “nigra hora” or “niger ille dies” with reference to death (See e.g.Tibullus and Propertius passim) .

Primary sources:

- Livy, Ab Urbe Condita,  book 22. chapter 10. section 6 : “si atro die faxit insciens, probe factum esto”

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0200%3Abook%3D22%3Achapter%3D10

- Cicero, Pro A.Caecina, 27 : “Clodius, cui nomen est  Phormio nec minus niger nec minus confidens quam ille Terentianus Phormio”

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.+Caec.+27&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0013

- Macrobius,  Saturnalia, book 1, chapter 16. section 21:” Dies autem postriduanos ad omnia maiores nostri cavendos putarunt, quos etiam atros velut infausta appellatione damnarunt: eosdem tamen nonnulli communes velut ad emendationem nominis vocitaverunt”.

http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Macrobius/Saturnalia/home.html

Note that Macrobius says that “dies atri”, aka “dies postriduani”, i.e.  the days immediately following  the Kalendae, Nonae and Idus of each month,  are days of bad omens .
We know, in fact, that "Dies atri" were "dark" days in which fire should not be lit and sacrifices should not be offered in altars; temples should not celebrate public worship; all religious ceremonies are private but without sacrifices; starting new projects should be avoided, and certain gods, including Iuppiter and Ianus, may not be named.

Answer (score 5):

There are several sources that equate **albus-candidus** with **ater-niger**, which makes *niger* to be the opposite of *candidus* - a shiny black, and *ater* to be the opposite of *albus* - a dull black. As @fdb comments it is stated explicitly in L&S dictionary (for example [under *candidus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=candidus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)):

> opp. niger, a glistening black; while albus is a lustreless white,
> opp. ater, a lustreless black; cf. Serv. ad Verg. G. 3, 82; lsid.
> Orig. 12, 1, 51; Doed. Syn. III. p. 193 sq.) (class., and in the poets
> very freq.; in Cic. rare).

The issue of color is dealt in [*Be Not Afraid of the Dark by Shelley P. Haley*](https://ms.fortresspress.com/downloads/0800663403_Chapter%20one.pdf) pages 31-33, and we can find there the same idea:

> Albus and ater connote a matte-like quality, whereas candidus and
> niger imply luster and brightness.

Indeed there are scriptural examples that contrast the opposites: *albus* with *ater* and *candidus* with *niger*. Examples that Haley brings:

> **candida** me docuit **nigras**
> odisse puellas . . . (CIL 4.1520) [from graffito]

> nec scire utrum sis **albus** an **ater** homo (Cattulus 93)

---

Let us hope however that the above-given distinction is not based on those contrasts, since as [my collocations-tool suggests](https://danelh.github.io/collocations/?lemma=niger&algo=w2), *niger* is contrasted both with *albus* and *candidus* in about the same rate. In fact L&S itself [mentions](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=albus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) "exceptions to the general rule" (where *albus* is contrasted with *niger* instead of *ater*) :

> The following are examples of the opposition of albus and niger (instead of ater) as exceptions to the gen. rule; so always in Lucr. (who also uses albus and candidus or candens promiscuously), 2, 810; 822 sqq.; 731 sq.; 790; 767-771. Once in Cic.: quae alba sint, quae nigra dicere, Div. 2, 3; so Phaedr. 3, 15, 10; Ov. M. 2, 541; cf. with id. ib. 2, 534 and 535; also id. ib. 12, 403; 15, 46; id. H. 15, 37 al.: “albi et nigri velleris,” Vulg. Gen. 30, 35: “non potes unum capillum album facere aut nigrum,” ib. Matt. 5, 36.—

We also find in Ovid ater-candidus and niger-candidus contrast in the same verse:

> candida de nigris et de candentibus atra facere

This "promiscuous" usage of *albus* and *candidus* by several authors might indeed suggest, I think, that likewise any distinction between *ater-niger* should be taken with a grain of salt. Nor we should ignore that across time modification in meaning do happen.

Answer (score 2):

I was taught in university Latin (I took it through graduate school) that ater was 'dull' and niger 'shiny' black.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer! Do you know of a source where others could verify this, such as a dictionary or a textbook?